# Usar/Escapar @ em view CSHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Estou com um código jQuery na pagina CSHTML e estou com problema para validar o email com uma expressão regular, pois o `@` é um comando Razor em .NET. Como proceder para resolver este problema?

Segue o script:

```
$("#formEsqueceuSenha").submit(function(event) {
        $(".message").hide();
        $(".Error").hide();
        var sEmail = $("#email").val();
        if ((sEmail == '') || (sEmail == null)) {
            $("#email").focus();
            $(".message")
                .text('Por favor, informe um email válido.')
                .show();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var filtro = "/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i";
            if (!filtro.test(sEmail)) {
                $("#email").focus();
                $(".message")
                    .text('E-mail digitado esta invalido. Por favor corrigir.')
                    .show();
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

E o erro que ocorre:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como a pesquisa não ajuda eu não achei mas tenho certeza que isto foi perguntado recentemente. Se não me engano foi o @Cigano que respondeu, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: @bigown A meu ver, essa pergunta já está respondida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para escapar, onde tem `@` coloca `@@`.

Ficando assim:

```
 var filtro = "/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i";
```